# How to search folder an files in Google Share Drive using Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I wonder if it is possible to search folder/files in Shared Drive using Google API. I read the Google Drive API guides and searching all over the web for documentation. It seems like we can only search at drive level, but no in folder level. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the q parameter and parents in.

Answer (score 1):

### It is absolutely possible to search for files in shared drives with the method [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

You just need to make sure that the parameters `includeItemsFromAllDrives` and `supportsAllDrives` are both set to `true`.

Sample curl request:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&q=name%20contains%20%22Hello%20World%22&supportsAllDrives=true`